# Iterating through a List to show in TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, treeview

I have four lists that I am trying to get the contents to show up in a `TreeView` on my `Form`.
My current problem is that only the last item in each list is showing up in the view.
I am sure it has something to do with how I am iterating through the list but I am pretty stuck on how to get each individual list item to show up in the tree.

My tree structure is:

```
Dog
   Husky
      huskylist
   Chiwawa
      chiwawlist
Cat
   Siamese
       siameselist
   Tabby
        tabbylist
```

My code for the `Form` where the tree view is:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Model m_modelObj;
    public Form1(Model modelObj)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        m_modelObj = modelObj;

        List<Tabby> tabbyList = m_modelObj.TabbyList;
        List<Siamese> siameseList = m_modelObj.SiameseList;
        List<Husky> huskyList = m_modelObj.HuskyList;
        List<Chiwawa> chiwawaList = m_modelObj.ChiwawaList;

       //tree code

        //add husky list
        TreeNode node8 = null;
        foreach (var item in huskyList)
        {
            node8 = new TreeNode(item.name);       
        }

        TreeNode[] husky = new TreeNode[] { node8 };

        //add chiwawa list
        TreeNode node9 = null;
        foreach (var item in chiwawaList)
        {
            node9 = new TreeNode(item.name);
        }

        TreeNode[] chiwawa = new TreeNode[] { node9 };

        //dog breed
        TreeNode node2 = new TreeNode("Husky", husky);
        TreeNode node3 = new TreeNode("Chiwawa", chiwawa);
        TreeNode[] dog = new TreeNode[] { node2, node3 };

        //dog parent
        TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode("Dogs", dog);
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);

        //add tabby list
        TreeNode nodes = null;

        foreach (var item in tabbyList)
        {
            nodes = new TreeNode(item.name);
        }

        TreeNode[] tabby = new TreeNode[] { nodes };

        //add siamese list
        TreeNode node7 = null;
        foreach (var item in siameseList)
        {
            node7 = new TreeNode(item.name);
        }

        TreeNode[] siamese = new TreeNode[] { node7 };

        //cat breed
        TreeNode node4 = new TreeNode("Siamese", siamese);
        TreeNode node5 = new TreeNode("Tabby", tabby);
        TreeNode[] cat = new TreeNode[] { node4, node5 };

        //cat parent
        treeNode = new TreeNode("Cats", cat);
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void addDetailsBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string animalType = comboBoxAnimalType.SelectedItem.ToString();
        this.Hide();
        PetInfoForm aPetInfoForm = new PetInfoForm(animalType, m_modelObj);
        aPetInfoForm.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();
        aPetInfoForm.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may need to revisit your code.

For eg. you are replacing node9 inside your for loop. you will see the last node in the chiwawa. 

You can actually do something similar to chiawawa.Nodes.add(new TreeNode(item.name))  or use lambda select

Comment: You could take some self-advice from your "tree structure" and define some level of abstraction for your classes, to generate a more "compact" list of *Animals*. Then LINQ will be you friend.

Comment: you are creating `node8 ` in loop and overwrite it on every iterations.. so value in that will be the last value of iteration.. and then you add that in tree list.. so on tree list.. there will be last value only..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Create Object and Dynamic array in c# [Refer here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/c63ec5/object-and-dynamic-array-in-C-Sharp/)
>
> TreeView Basic to understand [Refer here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/treeview)

when you are creating the sub nodes you are overwrite the instance. you should maintain the nodes in a array.

```
        //tree code

        //add husky list
        List<TreeNode> node8 = new List<TreeNode>();
        foreach (var item in huskyList)
        {
            node8.Add(new TreeNode(item.name));
        }

        TreeNode[] husky = node8.ToArray();

        //add chiwawa list
        List<TreeNode> node9 = new List<TreeNode>();
        foreach (var item in chiwawaList)
        {
            node9.Add(new TreeNode(item.name));
        }

        TreeNode[] chiwawa = node9.ToArray();

        //dog breed
        TreeNode node2 = new TreeNode("Husky", husky);
        TreeNode node3 = new TreeNode("Chiwawa", chiwawa);
        TreeNode[] dog = new TreeNode[] { node2, node3 };

        //dog parent
        TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode("Dogs", dog);
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);

        //add tabby list
        List<TreeNode> nodes = new List<TreeNode>();

        foreach (var item in tabbyList)
        {
            nodes.Add(new TreeNode(item.name));
        }

        TreeNode[] tabby =nodes.ToArray();

        //add siamese list
        List<TreeNode> node7 = new List<TreeNode>();
        foreach (var item in siameseList)
        {
            node7.Add(new TreeNode(item.name));
        }

        TreeNode[] siamese = node7.ToArray();

        //cat breed
        TreeNode node4 = new TreeNode("Siamese", siamese);
        TreeNode node5 = new TreeNode("Tabby", tabby);
        TreeNode[] cat = new TreeNode[] { node4, node5 };

        //cat parent
        treeNode = new TreeNode("Cats", cat);
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
```

Or 
Using LINQ you can create the tree like this

```
        // Code Using Linq
        TreeNode husky = new TreeNode("Husky", huskyList.Select(x => new TreeNode(x.name)).ToArray());
        TreeNode chiwawa = new TreeNode("Chiwawa", chiwawaList.Select(x => new TreeNode(x.name)).ToArray());
        TreeNode Siamese = new TreeNode("Siamese", siameseList.Select(x => new TreeNode(x.name)).ToArray());
        TreeNode Tabby = new TreeNode("Tabby", tabbyList.Select(x => new TreeNode(x.name)).ToArray());
        //parent nodes
        treeView1.Nodes.AddRange(new[] {
            new TreeNode("Dog", new TreeNode[] { husky, chiwawa }),
            new TreeNode("Cat", new TreeNode[] { Siamese, Tabby })
            });
```

Comment: Instead of the last two lines you can use `TreeView.Nodes.AddRange`. It's equivalent to `BeginUpdate` + a couple of `Nodes.Add` + `EndUpdate`.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Thanks. Answer is edited as you expected. Why Add Range ? [refer here](http://scottdorman.github.io/2007/09/21/Add-vs.-AddRange/)